# how to convert csv file header to Row object in pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, apache-spark, pyspark

in my `csv` file I have 2500 columns so I wanted to convert header into ROW object to do comparison with expected schema.

or

I want to compare columns from `dataframe` to row object?

```
csv file= is | separated
```

I have tried

1. read file into dataframe.
2. header= df._jdf.schema().treeString()
3. convert to string
4. remove all char other than column names
5. convert string into list
6. create blank Row object
7. use this list as value and convert it to dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can read the CSV as a dataframe df and compare the schemas using df.schema or df.columns.